# CSS how to vertical align my text and text color

Tags: html, css

This is my output now

[image]

This is the output I want

[image]

My coding:

```
.buttons{
background-image:url("SlicingImage/button_unselect.png");
margin: none;
height: 53px;
width: 180px;
text-transform:uppercase;
text-align:center;
position:relative;
vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

HTML :

```
<li class="buttons">home</li>
```

But nothing changed :(

Comment: use line-height according to your button height

Comment: The look and position of your background image looks  different when the button is active

Answer (score 4):

**General tip** : if its just a link and not a paragraph, always give `line-height` equal to div height to align your text vertically in the middle
here add `line-height:53px;` to your class

Answer (score 0):

`Vertical-align: bottom;` works only with table-attributes like `Table-cell` or `Table-Row`

So:

```
.buttons{
   background-image:url("SlicingImage/button_unselect.png");
   margin: 0;
   height: 53px;
   width: 180px;
   text-transform:uppercase;
   text-align:center;
   position:relative;
   vertical-align:bottom;
   display: table-cell
}
```

You need to play with this; here a explanation about it: http://www.onenaught.com/posts/201/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.buttons{
background-image:url("SlicingImage/button_unselect.png");
margin: none;
/*height: 53px;
width: 180px;*/
padding: 30px 30px;
text-transform:uppercase;
text-align:center;
position:relative;
vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the vertical align does not work like that for what your'e trying to do.

you need to use line-height or padding to resolve this issue.

i would try line-height first

```
   .buttons { line-height: 100px; }
```

and also remove the height: 53px from your code. But adjust line-height accordingly.

Or you could also try

```
   .buttons { padding-top: 16px; }
```

and adjust accordingly